# Error loading custom frameworks in ad-hoc distribution

Tags: ios, swift, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a custom framework called "MySupportKit" and I have included "MySupportKit.framework" in my project's `Embedded Binaries`. It builds and runs fine in the simulator, but when I install it on a physical test device, I get a crash and this is what the logs say:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/MySupportKit.framework/MySupportKit
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/60A38B03-39C9-4755-9F62-D37ABF1E77D3/MySupport.app/MySupport
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/60A38B03-39C9-4755-9F62-D37ABF1E77D3/MySupport.app/Frameworks/MySupportKit.framework/MySupportKit: mmap() error 1 at address=0x100144000, size=0x00014000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/60A38B03-39C9-4755-9F62-D37ABF1E77D3/MySupport.app/Frameworks/MySupportKit.framework/MySupportKit
  Dyld Version: 353.12
```

I'm not sure what more to do. I have code signed both my framework and my app with the enterprise distribution provisioning profile.

EDIT: This is for iOS

Comment: Is this iOS or OS X?

Answer (score 0):

The framework is probably private, i.e. part of the App Bundle. Make sure you "copy files to the directory" when dragging in the framework, and tell the target to include it.

Comment: It is part of the app bundle I believe. When I drag the framework from products into "Embedded Binaries" it doesn't give me an option to copy

Comment: No, the option appears when you drag it into the project sidebar.

Comment: MySupportKit is already there in my sidebar, and MySupportKit.framework is already under my products

Comment: Can you try deleting it and re-adding it?